# Creating a Nth size grid using an array

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

How would I create an Nth size array where all the values are the same such that it can form a grid. I'm pretty new to coding and just started with arrays.

This is my code so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array_design {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner Row = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter length of row");
            int row = Row.nextInt();
    
    Scanner Col = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter length of column");
            int col = Col.nextInt();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String[][] GameBoard = new String [row][col];
        
        GameBoard[][] = for (int J = 1; J <= row; J = J + 1) {
            for (int I = 1; I <= col; I = I + 1) {
                 
                
                System.out.print("*");
                }
        
                // if user input equal declared variable
                System.out.println("");
                                        } 
}
        
        
        
    }

}
```

Comment: See Arrays.fill()

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 2 scanners, one will do.  Also, if you're only going to store a single character on each space, use a char instead of a String.  You should move this to a GameBoard class and create an init() and output() method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter length of row");
    int row = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter length of column");
    int col = scanner.nextInt();

    char[][] gameBoard = new char [row][col];
 
    //Init the board
    for (int i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++) {
        Arrays.fill(gameBoard[i], '*');
    }
    
    //output the board
    for (int i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(gameBoard[i]));
    }
}
```

Comment: okay, thanks bro. It does make sense that using a char would be better.

Answer (score 0):

What is going on with your code?

`GameBoard[][] = for (int J = 1; J <= row; J = J + 1)`

Anyway, the way I would do this is probably

```
public class Array_design
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //initialize Scanner from System.in

        System.out.println("Enter length of row");
        int row = input.nextInt(); //input row
        System.out.println("Enter length of column");
        int col = input.nextInt(); //input column

        String[][] GameBoard = new String[row][col]; //initialize gameboard

        for (String[] arr : GameBoard) for (String s : arr) //enhanced-for loops
            s = "*"; //assign a value to every element in GameBoard; change this to whatever
    }
}
```